# Why is it that $[\alpha^n] \ge \alpha^n/2$ for $n \ge 1$?

Tags: inequality

I'm reading through the proof of Etemadi's law of large numbers, and one of the inequalities that are used states that

$[\alpha^n] \ge \alpha^n/2$ for $n \ge 1$.

I seem to be perplexed by this inequality. Is this proven inductively? How would one make sense of the double bracket that would occur?

Comment: What do the brackets means?

Comment: For which $\alpha$? It's trivial for $0 \le \alpha < 1$ and false for integer $\alpha \ge 1$.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC The least integer less than or equal the given number.

Comment: @HansEngler I stated it reversed; now it's fixed.

Comment: @AlgebraicsAnonymous, I think you mean the *greatest* integer less than or equal to the given number. (I.e., you want to get as close as possible from below, not as far away as possible.)

Comment: Yes, sorry about that @BarryCipra

Comment: @AlgebraicsAnonymous, no problem, it's an easy thing to get backwards; I've done something like it myself many a time. Incidentally, can you provide an explicit reference (with a link, if possible) to the proof you're reading? I googled my way to a couple of Etemadi's papers, but couldn't find the inequality you cite.

Comment: I've found this: http://verso.mat.uam.es/~pablo.fernandez/prueba-LFGN-Etemadi.pdf The inequality is not to be found in Etemadi's original paper, because he left out many steps. The original paper is here: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01013465 @BarryCipra

Comment: @AlgebraicsAnonymous, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note the inequality is not true if $\alpha^n\lt1$, so presumably there is a tacit assumption that $\alpha\ge1$. In any event, we may as well prove that $\lfloor x\rfloor\gt x/2$ for all $x\ge1$ (and then substitute $x=\alpha^n$). Since $\lfloor x\rfloor\gt x-1$ always holds, we have, for $x\ge1$,

$$2\lfloor x\rfloor=\lfloor x\rfloor+\lfloor x\rfloor\gt(x-1)+1=x$$

so $\lfloor x\rfloor\gt x/2$.